# How do I use offsetChildrenHorizontal() in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I (perhaps mistakingly) understand that the method `offsetChildrenHorizontal(int dx)` within the new `RecyclerView` class should offset all of the children within the `RecyclerView` by the given distance - allowing the user to scroll past the first item.

Am I wrong in saying this?

If I'm correct, why might this not be taking effect? Do I need to include something to redraw the children?

Answer (score 1):

That method is intended to be used by LayoutManager while the layout is scrolling (or any time it wants to move children). 
You should not be calling it outside the LayoutManager.

On the other hand, if you call it, yes it will move the children (it simply  calls [offsetLeftAndRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#offsetLeftAndRight(int)) on all children) but next time layout runs, layout manager will probably revert your changes.